# I am able to display an image in streamlit but getting error Invalid binary data format: <class 'PIL.Image.Image'> while downloading it

Tags: python, numpy, streamlit

```py
import streamlit as st
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import io, img_as_float
from skimage.restoration import denoise_nl_means, estimate_sigma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file = st.file_uploader("Please upload a plantar thermogram file", type=["jpg", "png"])
if file is None:
    st.text("Please upload an image file")
else:
    pic = Image.open(file)
    st.image(pic, use_column_width=1000)
    img = (img_as_float(pic))
    sigma_est = np.mean(estimate_sigma(img, multichannel=True))
    denoise_img = denoise_nl_means(img, h=1.15 * sigma_est, fast_mode=True,patch_size=5, 
    patch_distance=3, multichannel=True)
    st.image(denoise_img,caption= "Denoised file", use_column_width=400)
    st.download_button(label="Download image",
                        data=denoise_img,
                        file_name="Denoised.png", 
                        mime="image/png")
```

Comment: Please click [edit] and try to improve your question by removing everything that is unrelated to the problem and being more specific about which line is causing the problem and showing the first few bytes of the parameters you use on that line. You will probably find the answer yourself if you do that. Thank you.

Comment: The image in `denoise_img` is in uncompressed binary format. Did you try to compress it to png before passing to `download_button`?

Comment: *do not tag unrelated technologies*. I've removed the OpenCV tag.

Comment: @Markus no this is my entire code, could you help me to do that please!

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you, I will follow it in my next work.

Comment: The easiest way to compress the image to the desired file format is to write it to a temporary file. Then you can open the temporary file as binary data file handle and pass it to `download_button`.